# node js mysql Cannot Enqueue a query after calling quit

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using node.js and mysql, to run sql commands frequently.

I am getting this error: `Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit`.

This is when I do

```
connection = mysql.createConnection(sqlDetails);
connection.connect();
```

and

```
connection.end();
```

If I comment the `.connect` and `.end` lines, then I get the error `ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections`.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087924/cannot-enqueue-handshake-after-invoking-quit

Comment: According to this https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#error-handling, it says to define your connection one, then just use that always. I did that, but now I'm not sure where to put my `connection.end()`. It says `You can listen on the error event to handle server disconnection and for reconnecting purposes.` but im not sure which function to put it in...

Comment: you should close one global connection the first request done, do not use a connection pool and grab a connection for each request separately or dont close the connection in the request handlers

Answer (score 2):

If you actually want to close connection (why? if you 'run sql commands frequently' you probably want to reuse it, or even better - use connection pool) you need to do that in query result callback. All commands are put into commands queue and processed sequentially.

This is what you are doing:

- open connection stream to mysql
- add Handshake command to queue
- add Query command to queue
- add Quit command to queue, mark connection as closing
- start processing commands
- now Handshake is processed when connection in 'closing' state

Answer (score 2):

Since node js is asynchronous , connection.connect() and connection.end() gets executed parallely,

If you want to specify sequence of execution, use callbacks like

```
connection = mysql.createConnection(sqlDetails);
connection.connect(function(err,callback){
    connection.query(function(err,callback){
         connection.end();
 });
});
```