# How to write the JSON data to MySql Database on NodeJS?

Tags: mysql, json, database, node.js, firebird2.5

I have JSON data, which I got from my Firebird database. Now, I would like to create mysql connection and write the JSON data to MySql database on NodeJS. But when I am closing the Firebird connection and creating MySql connection and trying some query on it, it gives an error:

> events.js:85
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>               ^
>   Error: Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit.
>       at Protocol._validateEnqueue (/Users/myuser/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:196:16)
>       at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/myuser/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:129:13)
>       at Protocol.handshake (/Users/myuser/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
>       at Connection.connect (/Users/myuser/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:123:18)
>       at Server. (/Users/myuser/Documents/project/convert_fdb_to_mysql.js:34:14)
>       at Server.emit (events.js:110:17)
>       at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:491:12)
>       at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:111:23)
>       at Socket.socketOnData (_http_server.js:343:22)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)

I would like to fix this error and write my JSON to MySql database.
Can you please let me know how can i solve my problem?

And any suggestions for transfer JSON data to MySql database?

Thanks,

This is my code for getting data from Firebird db:

```
var fb = require('firebird');
var util = require('util');
var http = require('http');
// mySQL connection
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    socketPath: '/tmp/mysql.sock',
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'mysql_db'
});
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    // Firebird connection
    var con = fb.createConnection();
    con.connectSync('FIREBIRD.FDB', 'SYSDBA', 'masterkey', '');
    var rs = con.querySync('SOME SQL Query');
    var rows = rs.fetchSync("all", true);
    con.disconnect(); // Firebird disconnect
    connection.connect(); // mysql connect
    connection.query('SOME SQL Query', function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(rows[0]);
    });
    connection.end(); // mysql disconnect
    res.write('[');
    rows.forEach(function (r) {
        res.write(JSON.stringify(r) + ',');
    });
    res.end(']');
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Comment: cool, synchronous actions inside of an http request handler. Solid.

Comment: This part of the error message: `Unhandled 'error' event` suggests that there is an error handler missing. Adding said error handler would give you an error message that you can act upon

Comment: The second part of the error suggests that you're ending something that isn't done yet, such as that mysql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method works!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14247110/5344483

And for JSON to MySql :

```
Write queries with "JSON.stringify(r.FIELD_NAME)"
```