# Node js mysql query gives error when executed second time

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, node-mysql

I am trying to make a REST api in node using express. When i open the url in browser the first time, it runs fine and gives me the correct output. But when I hit the api url the second time, the app crashes with the error :

> events.js:141
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit.

This is the code I'm using :

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var app = express();
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'USER_NAME',
  password: 'PASSWORD'
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
var port = 3333;

app.get('/api/users/:user_id', function(req, res){
    var lead_id = req.params.user_id;

    connection.connect();

    connection.query('use DB_NAME;', function (err) {
        if(err) throw err;

        connection.query('select * from users where user_id = ' + user_id, function (err, rows) {
            if(err) throw err;

            res.json(rows);
            connection.end();
        });
    });
});

app.listen(port);
console.log("The app is running on port " + port);
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Consider using a pool instead of a single connection. When you want a connection use pool.getConnection() and when you're done with it use connection.release();

Answer (score 5):

Just remove `connection.connect()` and `connection.end()`. Then it should work.

`connection.connect()` should be called once or none. Because `connection.query` will connect I'd it not connected.

PS - `connection.connect()` need to be called when the connection is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087924/cannot-enqueue-handshake-after-invoking-quit) to remove the redudant connection. This was the first result of a google search of the error message - always try to google error messages before asking SO.