# Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error

Tags: mysql, node.js

Hi I am new to nodejs and trying the connect the Mysql. 
I am really troubled with the error  **Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error.**
a) I am not using connection pooling so as not to complicate for start.
b) I had written connection.connect() at the start of code but removed it as I read in a link that it is not required. (refer below link)
[Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087924/cannot-enqueue-handshake-after-invoking-quit)

Below is the format for all my queries.

```
function matchFirstName(person_name){
              var query = "select firstName,lastname, username,securityRole from users where firstName='"+person_name+"'" ;
              connection.query(query, 
                function (err, rows) {
                    if (err || rows.length === 0) {
                        if(err){
                            console.log("error " + err);                
                            connection.end();
                        }
                    }
                    else{  
                        // some code or call to a different function which too might call a query in the same manner
                    }
            });
        }
```

Someone please suggest a permanent solution to this. 
I have tried removing connection.end() from my code as well but that too didnt help. This error pops up suddenly.

Update:
I think I found the reason. First some query that I use (a query which normally works) gives a **ETIMEDOUT** issue and then every following query fails.
I increased the connectTimeout from 60000 to 120000 ms and added the following code.

```
connection.on('error', function (err){
     if(err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT' ){
         connection.connect();
     }
});
```

Will this solve my problem?

Comment: seems like that you have an previous error , is your query is the first qiery in your program ? and in which line exactly you got that error ?

Comment: @HassanAhmed - No this is not a first query.   Also I edited my finding above I am getting a ETIMEDOUT error and then all my following queries fail.

Comment: so , i think that the error may be normal behavior , this maybe because an uncaught exception in a past failed query .

Comment: @HassanAhmed - So is my solution to add the error handler correct then? I have added this just below create.connection .  Or should this be added to every query ?

Comment: or with better way , fix the query which cause the failing .