# How to display nodejs mysql results on html page?

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io

I am learning Nodejs as an alternative to PHP which I am familiar with. Typically I would use Ajax to call PHP scripts to return json data and work from there. It is pretty simple to show it on a website.

Now I am trying to us Nodejs to load data from a MySQL database on page load and show it on the html page. The following is my app.js script.

I have two ideas listed below #1 using socket.io and #2 just loading it, they are not running concurrently, just different attempts.

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

//mysql

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '...',
    user: '...',
    password: '...',
    database: '...'
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
    socket.on('typing', (data) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('typing', data);
    });
    socket.on('typing_clear', (data) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('typing_clear', data);
    });

    // #1 - This is one attempt but crashes the app if loaded from a second page... It works but then if I open a second browser and load the url it crashes the app. I just want this to load once each time a user goes to the URL to load historical data from the database.

    socket.on('get_posts', (data) => {
        connection.connect();

        connection.query('SELECT `status` FROM `training`', function (error, results) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
            var string = JSON.stringify(results);
            // console.log(string);
            io.emit('get_posts', string);

        });

        connection.end();

    });

});


// #2 - This is another attempt. It grabs the data and successfully console log the data. I don't know what do from there. How can I get it to the client side JS page to use json parse and display it.

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT `status` FROM `training`', function (error, results) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    var string = JSON.stringify(results);
    console.log(string);

});

connection.end();


http.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Socket.IO server running at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});
```

I have a second JS script on the client side that does front end stuff with socket.io and others.

Am I going about this wrong?

---

Edit:
Here is the relevant part of the client side JS script.

```
load();
function load() {
    socket.emit('get_posts', "none");
}

socket.on('get_posts', function (data) {

    var results = JSON.parse(data);

    jQuery.each(results, function (index, item) {

        var status = item.status;
        var sticky = '<div class="sticky">' + status + '</div>';
        $("#messages").append(sticky);
    });

    var x = '<div class="sticky">END</div>';
    $("#messages").append(x);
});
```

Error for #2:

I am doing this on local host to test. I do nodemon app.js and go to localhost:3000.

Looks great, loads the data and displays as expected. Then I open a second browser window to see how another person may see it. It loads the html but does not load the data and in the server console (VS Code) I get:

```
Socket.IO server running at http://localhost:3000/
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit.
    at Protocol._validateEnqueue (/Users/username_hidden/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:215:16)
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/username_hidden/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:138:13)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/username_hidden/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/Users/username_hidden/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/username_hidden/node/app.js:36:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Socket.emitUntyped (/Users/username_hidden/node/node_modules/socket.io/dist/typed-events.js:69:22)
    at /Users/username_hidden/node/node_modules/socket.io/dist/socket.js:428:39
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Connection._handleProtocolError (/Users/username_hidden/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:423:8)
    at Protocol.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Protocol._delegateError (/Users/username_hidden/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:10)
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (/Users/username_hidden/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:232:10)
    at Handshake.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (/Users/username_hidden/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:78:12)
    at /Users/username_hidden/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:236:14
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
  code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT',
  fatal: false
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

---

Found another post noting you do not need connection.connect(); and connection.end() if already connected. Seemed to have fixes it so far... Testing in progress.

Comment: your #2 is not an end point it just runs at the time you start the service once. but your sockets io looks good. now whats bothering you.

Comment: @PavanKumarTS, I added some more code and error codes with explanation. I am not sure what this means, I have been troubleshooting for a while but I am still learning. I am not sure emit makes sense either since other users may have already loaded the old data and do not need to see it again.

Answer (score 0):

Replce your second code with a REST api like below

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: dbConfig.HOST,
  user: dbConfig.USER,
  password: dbConfig.PASSWORD,
  database: dbConfig.DB
});

// open the MySQL connection
connection.connect(error => {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log("Successfully connected to the database.");
});
app.get('/get-status', (req, res) => {
     connection.query('SELECT `status` FROM `training`', function (error, results) {
         if (error) {
             console.log(error);
         }
         res.send(results);
     });
  });
```

Now from your front end you could just use ajax to get the REST data using jquery

```
jQuery.get( "/get-status", function( data ) {
    jQuery.each(data , function (index, item) {
        var status = item.status;
        var sticky = '<div class="sticky">' + status + '</div>';
        $("#messages").append(sticky);
    });
    var x = '<div class="sticky">END</div>';
    $("#messages").append(x);
});
```

Now what i have suggested abave is a REST api solution that is for your second case. If you like to use sockets on the first go it will be little bit tough to understand try understanding how websockets work then it will be easy.

Comment: Okay, if i try this method it works in browser window #1 but then I go into browser windows #2 it crashes.  I get events.js:292      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event Error: Cannot enqueue Handshake after invoking quit. Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:... plus a bunch of the same stuff.

Comment: That is issue with mysql connection. edit your nodejs app and create connection at the start. see the edited answer. like above and dont call connect and end each time

Comment: Okay, that is another step forward but eventually I get Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection. Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:   fatal: true, code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'. Addeding connection.end() gives the original error.

Comment: you can see related answers here https://stackoverflow.com/q/14087924/7887883. but i suggest https://bezkoder.com/node-js-rest-api-express-mysql/ for better example

Comment: you see the problem is mysql connection will be lost over time or if closed/disconnected manually. so its better to use conncept of connection handler or connection pooling so that connection is provided when its necessary

Comment: Thanks. I will look at the links and test pooling. I appreciate all of your help.